# Tense: Future Tense Query Will be usage

Tags: tenses

When do we use 'will be' + v3 form of verb? Example, 'I will be finished in an hr vs I will have finished in an hr.' What is the difference?

Comment: Consider how *They will have given her a call yesterday* doesn't swap around so easily. Closest might be *She will have been given a call yesterday*, but now you've lost the original subject, and adding *by them* does not sound right. Also, those uses of *will*  are for something in the past, not the future.

Comment: Use the simplest verb form you can get away with it. If it's available, use the simple past or present. And _will_ is virtually always contracted: _I'll, you'll, he'll, they'll, we'll, it'll,_ etc. are much more common than their separated variants. Generally English speakers don't use _will_ for future reference, unless they're generalizing. _Be going to_ (/gənə/) is more common, especially for things that are more likely (cf: _Watch out! That rock is gonna/*will fall!_

Comment: "I'll be finished in an hour" and "I'll have finished in an hour" are both acceptable among Brits, and I'd expect relevant Google 5-grams to show this (but tea calls).

Comment: [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I%27ll+be+finished+in%2CI%27ll+have+finished+in&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20%27ll%20be%20finished%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20%27ll%20have%20finished%20in%3B%2Cc0) indeed show both usages, but "I'll be finished in" is far more commonly observed. There's little difference in meaning, other than the verbal construction focusing more on the achieving, the adjectival on the achievement.

Answer (score 1):

In *I will be finished*, "finished" isn't functioning as a past participle, but as an adjective, meaning "complete, done".

In a different tense, it is "I'm finished".

As Tim Baverstock points out, it could in principle be passive "I will be finished" = "Something will finish me"; but this use is rare with an person as the subject. "The work will be finished" is more natural as a passive.

Answer (score 0):

If you substitute the verb 'eaten' or 'tickled' for 'finished', it looks like a switch between whether you are the actor or the recipient.

You can still understand 'I will be finished' to mean 'I will be ruined' (i.e. by someone/thing else).